# undefined method `html_safe' for #<Hash: when trying to make a Rails API using a layout file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, layout

I'm trying to make a simple layout file that returns JSON.

My `layout.json.rb` looks like this:

```
{
  data: yield
}.to_json
```

The file it's yielding to is `profile.json.rb`:

```
{
  profiles_returned: @profiles.count,
  profiles: @profiles
  }
```

I expect this to just return:

```
{data:{
  profiles_returned: @profiles.count,
  profiles: @profiles
  }}
```

but instead I'm getting: `undefined method`html_safe' for #`

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in IRB. Have you tried inspecting what the hash is before you call `to_json`?

Comment: `html_safe` is being called on `profile.json.rb` when I try to call it using yield, which is where the problem is. If I convert the contents in `profile.json.rb` into a string, the json gets produced just fine, but with a string where I call yield instead of the nested JSON I want. Does that make sense?